# Vue, Axios, making a get request to YouTube search API return 404

Tags: vue.js, axios, youtube

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to make a get request to YouTube API for a keyword. The query string now is returning 404 I a have added referring urls and have current api key.

My method where I am making call with axios.The location logs out fine.

```
async getYouTubeVideoId(location) {
    console.log({ location })
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="mykeyinquotes"&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=${location}`
      )
      console.log(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log({ error })
    }
  },
```

Here is where I am calling method

```
 async created() {
    this.getLocationData()
    await this.getWikiData(this.pickedLocation.name)
    await this.getYouTubeVideoId(this.pickedLocation.name)
    this.asyncDataStatus_fetched()
  }
```

Comment: Does it work with Postman?

Comment: API key should not be in quotes.

Comment: Have not tried postman yet

Comment: It was the quotes Ha Ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API key should not be in quotes.